# app.build's gcda/gcno files vs appTests.build's gcda/gcno files?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm attempting to configure code coverage for my iOS project.  I've set both project settings, "Generate Test Coverage Files" as well as "Instrument Program Flow" for both my app's target and my test target.  I also used Coverstory's gcovr flush hack to generate gcda files in iOS7.

My question is, when I run my tests on a cleaned build, I see gcda and gcno files, (for each one of my project's source files, eg AppDelegate.gcda is in both directories) in two directories:

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/**MyApp.build**/Objects-normal/i386/

and

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/**MyAppTests.build**/Objects-normal/i386/

What's the difference between how the gcno and gcda files are generated in each of these directories?  (There is some difference, because if I view the files in Coverstory, the coverage is different for some of the files).

Answer (score 0):

You have two different targets and you have enabled flags "Generate Test Coverage Files" for both the test targets "Instrument Program Flow".

MyApp.build contains code coverage while the build is running on simulator and MyAppTests shows your actual test code coverage.

The prior one is useful in certain cases for e.g you want to determine which section of the code is not used.

To avoid confusion you should always enable flags in your main target. When you run unit test case it will overwrite gcda files in the same folder always giving you latest information for both the configurations.